# Отключение исключений и RTTI в VS2017

Tags: c++, исключения, rtti

Смотрел видео Mike Acton и там рассказывалось, что в геймдеве не используют исключения, RTTI  и т.д.. Вопрос в следующем, можно ли как-то выставить компиляторы эти опции для отключения этих возможностей, либо просто их стоит избегать при использовании и все? За пример взять компилятор MSVS2017...

Comment: Скорее там не используют *встроенный* RTTI в силу его малой полезности. Так что его можно смело отключать. С исключениями другая история, но их-то как раз отключать не следует, да и не получится, даже если избегать их использования. На Windows SEH исключения и таблицы для раскрутки стека фактически обязательны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну RTTI ладно, вещь в какой-то мере спорная, а исключения-то чем не угодили?

Насчет RTTI просто - правой кнопкой на проекте, Properties, C++, Language, и выбираете 'No' в поле "Enable Run-Time Type Information". Исключения удалить из языка нельзя, просто их не используйте.

Если для вас С++ излишен, подумайте о использовании С. Там ни классов, ни исключений, ни шаблонов...

UPD: Кстати тут пришло в голову - если используются иерархии классов, то RTTI нужен, поскольку `dynamic_cast` это часть RTTI. А если вы классы не используете, тогда может и в самом деле подумать насчет С?

Comment: Можно ли передать компилятору в ручную допустим при помjщи cmake этот флаг?

Comment: @QuickDzen, можно, собственно в диалоге Properties указываются все соответствующие флаги. Конкретно этот - `/GR-`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Есть же способ для отключения исключений Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable C++ exception. За что данный пункт отвечает?

Comment: @QuickDzen, этот пункт не убирает исключения, он просто указывает модель обработки исключений. Подробнее про это можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=vs-2017).

Comment: @QuickDzen, дополнил ответ немного.

Comment: При использовании иерархий классов `dynamic_cast` задействующий RTTI совсем не нужен. Скорее его присутствие в коде будет выдавать проблему с этой самой иерархией.

Comment: @VTT, не понял вашу мысль... при использовании иерархии классов `dynamic_cast` не нужен? А зачем он тогда вообще нужен в таком случае?

Comment: Бытует мнение, что он вообще не нужен, но это радикальное мнение. Более мягкое говорит о том, что его использование крайне нежелательно и часто означает, что в коде есть архитектурная проблема.

Comment: @ixSci, подобные идеи регулярно возникают по тому или иному поводу. Вроде того, что у Правильного Панка должен быть гребешок, а Настоящий Программист не использует goto, или dynamic_cast, или исключения, тут насколько воображения хватит. По сути это просто разновидность сектанства. Архитектурная проблема конечно может повлечь за собой избыточное использование dynamic_cast, так она еще много чего другого может повлечь. А на самом деле это вещи несвязанные, dynamic_cast может встретиться и в плохом коде, и в хорошем. Судить по этому признаку о коде это бред полнейший.

Comment: Да я согласен, в целом, но проблема в том, что `dynamic_cast` действительно часто используют тогда, когда лучше обойтись без него. Всё-таки не так часто нужно действительно знать тип, по крайней мере реже, чем можно наблюдать использование подобного преобразования.